# Moving the focus to the Right side of an EditText when the Next button is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

I Need to change the focus to the edite text in the right side. I have alredy given the `android:nextFocusRight` But. it is not moving to the ridhtside. insted it move the focus to the down side.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/edt2"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this use **`android:imeOptions="actionNext"`** in your `edt1` `EditText` it will  work

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/edt2"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just have to use property "**nextFocusDown**" instead of "**nextFocusRight**" it will solve your Problem

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/edt2"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```